# Is it possible to insert data from two different web forms using one stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have data I need to insert into a row, but there's two different web forms where this data would be coming from. So on the first form let's say I have fields for `ProjectManager`, `ProjectName`, and `ProjectDescription`. On the second form, I have `Cost` and `Budget`.

Is it possible to use one stored procedure, to insert the data from both forms using just this procedure?

```
Insert into header (ProjectManager, ProjectName, ProjectDescription, Cost, Budget)
Values ('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five')
```

Would I need to do something different than that in SQL Server, or could this all be done in the C# code? Or both? Are there any examples of how one could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass a parameter to the stored procedure telling it what form is calling it. Keep in mind that a stored procedure should specialize in one thing, so this is likely to be not a good practice.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MultipleFormsCanCallMe
(
    @WhatFormCalledMe int
)
AS 
BEGIN
    IF @WhatFormCalledMe = 1
        --Do something
    ELSE
        --Do something else
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't have one table for fields like [IDProject], ProjectManager, ProjectName, and ProjectDescription and another table for Cost and Budget with a relation with the [IDProject].

This way you can have two stored procedures one for each table, remember the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 0):

Your life will be much simpler if you use Session Variables to save and pass all the information from one-page to another and on the final page when the user hits submit you pass all of those values to one stored procedure.

**Flow :**

```
WebForm1 (Collect First 3 Variables in Session Variables) --> Redirect To WebForm2 (Collect Last 2 variables ) --> Call SP and pass all 5 Variables.
```